# django allauth email login - always wrong

Tags: python, django, email, authentication, django-allauth

If I change my allauth authentication method to email in django settings I always get the following error:

```
The e-mail address and/or password you specified are not correct.
```

Even though the email matches the one in the database.

I tried this in a clean django project using the following settings:

```
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "optional"
```

I set email verification to optional to eliminate a source for the error but the issue remains regardless of whether or not I confirm the email address.

Comment: I am getting the same problem. when login using username its working,but login using email it is showing this error. Did you get the solution?

Comment: Nope sorry. I couldn't find a solution anywhere.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I faced the same problem. My arse was on fire because of deadline, hence I figured out a way around. Thought of sharing. I took the user instance by using the filter and then populated the POST by copying the data from original request.

```
self.user = User.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
```

then

```
self.request.POST = self.request.DATA.copy()
```

I was using REST Request objects, hence the `DATA`. You can create another mutable POST object using some method.Note that original POST is immutable and you can't add anything into it. And then finally

```
self.request.POST['login'] = self.user.username
```

and then calling the `form_valid` of `LoginView`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I had to switch to username password for the login in the end but thanks for the input I'll probably use that sometime in a coming project.

Comment: Same problem. I am using email only login at the moment and suddenly the app was failing. I added this to settings (for email only) via the allauth docs:```ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"``` Everything snapped back together.  HTH!

Answer (score 44):

Had same issue today, my solution was that I was missed the **AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS** step when installing allauth.

Ensure you have the following in your `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    # Needed to login by username in Django admin, regardless of `allauth`
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    # `allauth` specific authentication methods, such as login by e-mail
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)
```

See http://www.sarahhagstrom.com/2013/09/the-missing-django-allauth-tutorial for a helpful guide

Comment: This was the issue on my case too. Thanks!

Comment: Fixed my issue too

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue today and none of the above solutions helped.
The issue was coming from a custom login template I used to display input fields.

So either use the default way to render forms or make sure you are using `login` as a name for your email input field :

```
<input type="email" name="login" required="">
<input type="password" name="password" required="">
```

I previously was using `email` which was throwing an error

> Login doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but in case anyone comes across it. These are all the setting in settings.py i added in order to enable email login

```
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
```

Comment: This one ended up being my problem.